Maximization of a cubic form over the $14$-dimensional sphere
For any integers $i$ and $j$ such as $1\le i<j\le6$, let $x_{ij}$ be a nonnegative real number.
Is it true that, given the condition
$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le6}x_{ij}^2=1,$$
the sum
$$\sum_{1\le i<j<k\le6}x_{ij}x_{ik}x_{jk}$$
is maximized when all the $x_{ij}$'s are the same?

There's strong numerical evidence that this is indeed the case.

@AryehKontorovich : Yes, my numerical experiments, too, suggested that this is true.

The Lagrange  multipliers’ method gives  a system of $15$ equations $$\cases{a_{13} a_{23}+ a_{14} a_{24}+ a_{15} a_{25}+ a_{16} a_{26}=\lambda a_{12}\
\vdots\a_{15} a_{16}+ a_{25} a_{26}+ a_{35} a_{36}+ a_{45} a_{46}=\lambda a_{56}}$$

@PietroMajer : Yes, but I did not know how to use/solve this system. Perhaps, some combinatorics may help here.

If we put $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ and $a_{ii}:=0$,  the  $6\times 6$  symmetric matrix $A:=(a_{ij})_{ij}$ verifies….  something ($A^2=\lambda A$ ?)

@PietroMajer : I tried something like that, but this does not hold for the diagonal elements.

So $A^2=\lambda A +  D$ for a diagonal matrix $D$

@PietroMajer : Right, $D$'s $i$th diagonal entry is $\sum_j x_{ij}^2$.

and $\text{tr}A^2= \text{tr}D=2$

@IosifPinelis It seems to me that, in general, $$\text{tr} A^3 =\frac{n-2 }{\sqrt{n(n-1)}},(\text{tr}A^2)^{3/2},$$ for all symmetric matrices $A$ of order $n\ge2$ with zero diagonal entries, and equality iff moreover all non-diagonal entries are equal. There is some nice combinatorics, as you said.

(there are also changing sign maximisers,  for  changing sign to both the $i$-th  row and column  doesn’t change $\text{tr}A^m$)

@PietroMajer yes, since from the proof of the inequality we see that on eigenvalues level the only equality case is when all but one are equal to, say, $-\alpha$, then $A+\alpha I$ has rank one and the rest is easy

I saw it this way, but no so fast as you did. From the above $A^2=\lambda A+D$ one has that $D$ commutes with $A$, so $d_i$ is the same in any block partition of $A$ (because $d_i=d_j$ if $d_ia_{ij}=a_{ij}d_j$ with $a_{ij}\neq0$) . So for   each block $B$ of $A$, say of dim $k$, we have $B^2=\lambda B+ \mu I$, whence I can find (by induction!) $\lambda, \mu$ and spec(B), and conclude that $A$ has only one block because it is a maximiser.
(PS: the above displayed formula is of course an inequality, $\le$ not $=$).

@PietroMajer : You meant the corresponding inequality in place of the equality, right?

yes ,it’s a typo

Put $x_{ij}=x_{ji}$ and consider the symmetriс matrix $A=(x_{ij})$ with zeros on diagonal. Then $\operatorname{tr} A=0$, $\operatorname{tr} A^2=2\sum_{i<j} x_{ij}^2=2$ is fixed, denote it $2=30 \alpha^2$ and what should be maximized is nothing but $\operatorname{tr} A^3=6\sum_{i<j<k} x_{ij}x_{ik}x_{jk}$, the conjectured maximal value is $6{6\choose 3}\alpha^3=120\alpha^3$. So, for eigenvalues $t_i$ we have $\sum t_i=0$, $\sum t_i^2=30\alpha^2$ and want to prove $\sum t_i^3\leqslant 120\alpha^3$. If $t_1=\ldots=t_5=-\alpha$ and $t_6=5\alpha$, we have equality (and this is realized when all $x_{ij}$ are equal to $\alpha$).
Well, let's try the following standard trick. Imagine that we have $(t_i-5\alpha)(t_i+\alpha)^2\leqslant 0$ for all $i$, then sum up and get the bound of $\sum t_i^3$ via $\sum t_i^2$ which turns into equality in our case, so this bound is $120\alpha^3$ (a direct check: what we get is $\sum t_i^3\leqslant 3\alpha\sum t_i^2+6\cdot 5\alpha^3=120\alpha^3$). Ok, if not, say, if $t_6>5\alpha$, then we have $t_1^2+\ldots+t_5^2\geqslant \frac{(t_1+\ldots+t_5)^2}5=\frac{t_6^2}5>5\alpha^2$, also $t_6^2>25\alpha^2$ and $\sum t_i^2>30\alpha^2$, a contradiction.

This problem can be posed as finding a point satisfying a system of polynomial equations and inequalities. There exist a few software for solving them, such as QEPCAD (available in Sage) and RAGLib (available in Maple).
UPDATED. I've supplied the system composed of $\sum_{i<j} x_{i,j}^2=1$, $x_{i,j}\geq 0$, $c^2 = \binom{6}{3}^2/\binom{6}{2}^3$, $c>0$, and $\sum_{i<j<k} x_{i,j}x_{i,k}x_{j,k} > c$ to QEPCAD, requesting to find any point satisfying it, and it said that such point does not exist. However, along the way it comes with a lot of warnings about "The McCallum projection may not be valid."
Here is this calculation at SageCell.
Maybe RAGlib can do a better job here.

Hmm. What if your $c$ is negative?

@IosifPinelis: Oh! I forgot to specify $c>0$, but that's for good, since absence of solution with negative $c$ is wrong. In verbose mode I see a lot of warnings like "WARNING! Projection factor ... is everywhere zero in the cylinder over the cell ... of postive dimension.  The McCallum projection may not be valid.", which seems to affect the result.

Sorry, I don't know how to interpret this warning. Also, if my understanding is not mistaken, QEPCAD seems to have overlooked the case $c<0$, which makes its work seem questionable.

@IosifPinelis: That was my concern as well. The result cannot be trusted because of those warnings.

Thank you for your answer anyway. I somehow had forgotten that this problem is one of real algebraic geometry, and your answer was a good reminder about that. Mathematica does not seem to be able to handle this problem.
